# How to encode comments while generating a config file in Go and API v3 of the yaml package

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to learn to use YAML v3 while marshaling a struct to config yaml.

Note: Update: My original example was little over simplified. My actual requirements is below:

For example, I have:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Ec2 struct {
    Class string `yaml:"class"`
    Ip    string `yaml:"ip"`
}

type Vpc struct {
    Subnet string `yaml:"subnet"`
    Igw    interface{} `yaml:"igw"`

}

type Config struct {
    Ec2 Ec2 `yaml:"ec2"`
    Vpc Vpc `yaml:"vpc"`
}

func main() {
    c := Config{}
    bytes, err := yaml.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    ioutil.WriteFile("config.yaml", bytes, 0644)
}
```

Which create a file named `config.yaml` file in `pwd` like:

```
  ec2:
    class: ""
    ip: ""
  vpc:
    subnet: ""
    igw: null
```

But I am trying to generate config file (in this case config.yaml) like:

```
    ec2:
    # This section is for EC2
      class: ""
      ip: ""
    vpc:
    # This section is for VPC
      subnet: ""
      igw: null
```

Can this be achievable using `V.3`?

Comment: Did the answer below address what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I preferred to follow Method 1. But I am having difficulties to build the tree. In my example, I have over simplified the struct. My actual struct is little complex with nested struct within. ``` type Config struct { Ec2 Ec2 yaml:"ec2" Vpc Vpc yaml:"vpc" } type Ec2 struct { Class string yaml:"class" IP string yaml:"ip" } type vpc struct { Subnet string yaml:"subnet" .... } ``` and I wanted to comment all of those filed. Can I do that using Node type?

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to leverage `yaml.v3` and its comments feature:

- build a `yaml.Node` tree by hand (tedious maintenance; precise value updates)
- parse a template into a `yaml.Node` tree (easy maintenance; harder to value update)

---

**Method 1:**

Craft a YAML Node tree by hand:

```
config = &yaml.Node{
    Kind: yaml.DocumentNode,
    Content: []*yaml.Node{
        &yaml.Node{
            Kind: yaml.MappingNode,
            Content: []*yaml.Node{
                &yaml.Node{
                    Kind:        yaml.ScalarNode,
                    Value:       "ec2",
                    HeadComment: "# This section is for EC2",
                },
                &yaml.Node{
                    Kind:  yaml.ScalarNode,
                    Style: yaml.DoubleQuotedStyle,
                    Value: "", // <- field value goes here
                },

                &yaml.Node{
                    Kind:        yaml.ScalarNode,
                    Value:       "vpc",
                    HeadComment: "# This section is for VPC",
                },
                &yaml.Node{
                    Kind:  yaml.ScalarNode,
                    Style: yaml.DoubleQuotedStyle,
                    Value: "", // <- field value goes here
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Working Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/Z6iw29rHZXk

Output:

```
# This section is for EC2
ec2: ""
# This section is for VPC
vpc: ""
```

---

**Method 2:**

Read a template of your YAML schema e.g.

```
var yamlSchema = []byte(`

# EC2 header-comment
ec2: ""

# This section is for VPC
vpc: ""

`)
```

And then parse it at runtime into a `yaml.Node` tree like so:

```
var c yaml.Node
err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlSchema, &c)
```

But as a `yaml.Node` tree - which has nested slice of `yaml.Node`s - you'd need to programmatically find your field values so when you Marshal the config for writing, the values are paired with the correct fields.

For example, this *may* work today:

```
c.Content[0].Content[1].Value = ec2Value // dangerous
```

but not tomorrow, when the schema changes.

Traversing the map and looking for the field value `ec2` and then placing its value in the adjacent node would be the proper way.

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/qiIrsaDkyfw) shows how header/footer/inline comments can be added to the schema e.g.

```
# This section is for EC2
ec2: ""          # <-- place user input here
# footer EC2

# This section is for VPC
vpc: ""
```

Comment: I preferred to follow Method 1. But I am having difficulties to build the tree. In my example, I have over simplified the `struct`. My actual struct is little complex with nested struct within.

 ```
type Config struct {
    Ec2 Ec2 `yaml:"ec2"`
    Vpc Vpc `yaml:"vpc"`
}
type Ec2 struct {
Class string `yaml:"class"`
IP string `yaml:"ip"`
}

type vpc struct {
Subnet string `yaml:"subnet"`
....
}
```
and I wanted to comment all of those filed. Can I do that using Node type?